# SPARQL to get Wikidata items that have no P18 image but have a Commons image depicting them?

Tags: wikidata, sparql, wikimedia-commons

Many Commons images `depict` Wikidata concepts.

How to find these concepts, in particular those that do not have an `image` (P18) property?

The request should output the URIs of both the Wikidata item and the depicting Commons image(s).

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible yet, see https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T141602

Comment: @Ainali: I think I remember there was some kind of trick to achieve that, though... but I can not find it anymore. Maybe I just dreamt of it ^_^

Comment: @Ainali: I hope https://sdcquery.wmflabs.org can be a temporary solution, even though it is beta and says "do not use".